# Simplifying Prop Logic Formulas

Tags: logic

So I'm trying to simplify $(\lnot A\lor B)\land(\lnot A\land\lnot B)$ to $\lnot A\land \lnot B$. Here's what I tried doing, but I feel like its completely wrong.

$(\lnot A\lor B)\land(\lnot A\land\lnot B)$ = 
$( B\lor\lnot A)\land(\lnot A\land\lnot B)$ = 
$ B\lor\lnot A\land(\lnot A\land\lnot B)$ = .......

If anyone could point me to the right way, that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: begin with Commutation and Association:

$$\begin{split}&(\lnot A\lor B)\land(\lnot A\land\lnot B) \\\equiv~& (\lnot A\lor B)\land(\lnot B\land\lnot A)\\\equiv~& \big((\lnot A\lor B)\land\lnot B\big)\land\lnot A\end{split}$$

Answer (score 3):

> Simplify $\,(\lnot A \lor B) \land (\lnot A \land \lnot B)\,$ to $\, \lnot A \land \lnot B$.

Truth table for $\,(\lnot A \lor B) \land (\lnot A \land \lnot B)$:

```
A | B | ¬A | ¬B | (¬A ∨ B) | (¬A ∧ ¬B) | (¬A ∨ B) ∧ (¬A ∧ ¬B)
__|___|____|____|__________|___________|______________________
T | T | F  | F  | T        | F         | F
  |   |    |    |          |           | 
T | F | F  | T  | F        | F         | F
  |   |    |    |          |           | 
F | T | T  | F  | T        | F         | F
  |   |    |    |          |           | 
F | F | T  | T  | T        | T         | T
```

As you can see, $\,(\lnot A \lor \lnot B)\,$ and $\,(\lnot A \lor B) \land (\lnot A \land \lnot B)\,$ have the same truth values.